# Foreach no FPDI repete no mesmo local os dados

Tags: php, mvc

Eu dinâmicamente envio para este arquivo via controller os dados em uma array denominado $vacinas, estou usando composer por isso a importação do autoload. Acontece que as informações estão sendo imprimidas no mesmo local:

```
<?php

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf = new Fpdi();

$pdf->AddPage('L');
$pdf->setSourceFile("report/cartaoFront.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 5, 5, 290);

/**
 * Dados animal
*/


$pdf->addPage('L');
$pdf->setSourceFile("report/cartaoVerso.pdf");

$tplId = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplId, 5, 5, 290);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

foreach ($vacinas as $item) 
{
    
        $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
        
        // Nome Vacina
        $pdf->SetXY(12, 35);
        $pdf->Cell(5,0,$item['titulo_vacina'],0,1,"C");

        // Nome Méd Veterinário
        $pdf->SetXY(68, 35);
        $pdf->Cell(5,0,utf8_decode($item['nome_veterinario']),0,1,"C");

    
}

$pdf->Output();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E preciso que insira as informações abaixo de cada um. Eu tentei usando $pdf->getY() * 2 mas ele espaça muito, também tentei usando for só que ele acaba imprimindo 2 ou quantos dados retornar no mesmo campo.

**O que eu quero resolver com essa dúvida:**
Fazer com que o foreach não repita os dados no mesmo local e sim a cada interação incrementar (+ o valor do y anterior)

Eu tentei assim: `$pdf->SetXY(68, 35 + ($pdf->getY();` porém não deu certo também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
    $pdf->SetXY(12, 25 + ($pdf->getY()));
    $pdf->Cell(5,0,$item['titulo_vacina'],0,1,"C");

    
    $pdf->SetXY(68, ($pdf->getY()));
    $pdf->Cell(5,0,utf8_decode($item['nome_veterinario']),0,1,"C");
```

Ao invés de somar com o getY() com outros valores, apenas coloquei ele puro que ficou um abaixo do outro respeitando a ordem de proporção.